# boundedness in metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

The problem is : If $(X,d)$ is a metric space with metric $p(x,y) = min(1, d(x,y))$ then prove that any non empty subset of *X* is bounded

My solution is:
$min (1, d(x,y)) < 1$, hence $p(x,y) < 1$.
Also $p(x,y) \ge 0$,
therefore  $0 \le p(x,y) \le 1$.
Hence $(X,d)$ is bounded and therefore any subset of *X* will be bounded.

Request confirm if the logic is correct

Comment: $\min(1,d(x,y))\le1$

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference